# Import SCSS as string

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass-loader, raw-loader

I'm trying to import some SCSS into a Javascript file with mixed results.  I've found that this works:

**style.styleString.scss**

```
body {
    background: #556;
}

.test {
    &__child {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import "./index.style"; // making sure that nothing we do breaks normal SCSS importing

const css = require("!!raw-loader!sass-loader!./style.stringStyle.scss").default;
console.log(css);
```

`index.style.scss` is correctly compiled to a file and `style.stringStyle.scss` is correctly printed in the console.

What I'd like to do is move this loader pipeline into my webpack config.  This is what I have at the moment:

```
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import path from "path";

const config = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        "app": "./src/index.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.stringStyle.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    "raw-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader:"css-loader",
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".scss", ".css"],
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        }),
    ],
};

export default config;
```

**index.js**

```
import "./index.style"; // making sure that nothing we do breaks normal SCSS importing

const css = require("./style.stringStyle.scss").default;
console.log(css);
```

With this configuration, an empty string is printed to the console (`index.style.scss` still correctly renders to a file).

What am I doing wrong here?  I was sort of under the impression that using the inline `!` syntax in imports works just like lining up loaders in the config file, but I'm clearly missing something.

**Is it possible to setup loading SCSS files as CSS strings in my Webpack config?**

Comment: Looks like your file `/style.stringStyle.scss` has been interrupted by 2 rules not only one rule as you defined (one more is below your defined rule) so it's likely the issue I guess

Comment: @tmhao2005 ah!  Didn't realize two rules could apply - thought it would just pick the first matching test.  Adding a negative lookbehind fixed the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SCSS tracking rules are getting applied to `style.stringStyle.scss`.  Adding a negative look-behind to the normal import rule's test regex will make sure only the correct rule is selected:

```
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import path from "path";

const config = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        "app": "./src/index.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.stringStyle.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    "raw-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /(?<!\.stringStyle)\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader:"css-loader",
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".scss", ".css"],
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        }),
    ],
};

export default config;
```